# Is there a default ID assigned to any object instance in .NET?

Tags: .net, object, instance, uniqueidentifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET unique object identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750947/net-unique-object-identifier)

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, is there a unique, immutable object ID I can access for each object instance in .NET?

I'm asking this because I find myself writing the same code many times: Add a field or a property named *Id*, with type of `Guid`. This is useful mainly for logging purpose.
Example:

```
Logger.Debug(string.Format("about to save data to file, my id is {0}", this.Id));
```

Is there something built in the .NET framework instead of coding and using `this.Id`?
Surely there's nothing immediate, but maybe something using .NET internals.

Update:

I intentionally don't want to use the `GetHashCode` technique, or any related hash code mechanism.

Comment: Also interesting and related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994277/memory-address-of-an-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Check [Jon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9789370/445517) on the duplicate question. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such field.

Some "alternatives" may be [using the object's [default] hash code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5704035/166390) or using [ObjectIDGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994372/166390), but these serve different purposes...

Comment: :( maybe something in the internals area?