# How can I find all references of string from the object?

Tags: c#, .net, string, object, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Track all object references in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707421/track-all-object-references-in-c-sharp)

Strings are *reference types*. They have two parts; an `object` and a `reference to object`. For example;

```
string str1 = "Soner";
string str2 = str1;
```

`str1` and `str2` are references to same object, `"Soner"` is an object. Is there any way to find all references point to the same object? In this case, I try to find `str1` and `str2` just using `"Soner"` object?

Of course, I didn't know also how to access to `string` object without any reference to it. I want to know if there is a way.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all variables that reference a specific object in runtime at a specific point in time?

Comment: @Oded Nearly, I want to find all references to the same object. As you say, I could be only for runtime right?

Comment: look at [Mark Gravell's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) answer [to the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/707459/1471381). He says you can gatter all references of an object using SOSAssist.

Comment: And don't forget that strings are immutable and when you change them they are not the old object anymore.

Comment: @mahditahsildari Of course, but in my case there is no string changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built in way to get all the refercences to an object at runtime within your CLR process. The  [GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0fwz4wc(v=vs.80).aspx) does not give any information about object references.

Everything you could do is building custom "tracker" that keeps references to the objects after they've been added explicitly. [Jon Skeet describes the basic idea here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5704035/808723).

Comment: But, If I try `s.GetHashCode()` , `r.GetHashCode()` and `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode("Soner")`. First and second gave me same result but third didn't.

Comment: Go with `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode` if you want to use the hashcode to track the objects yourself, since `GetHashCode` can be overridden by classes (`System.String` does that) resulting in custom implementation. See [my paste](http://pastebin.com/fr6m6JHA) for an example